# background processing of videos using sidekiq rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video

How do one configure sidekiq for background processing of videos and to display videos from a temporary location until a video is getting processed in background. Suggest me some ideas.

video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :video, :event_id,:user_id
  belongs_to :event 
  has_many :favorite_videos, dependent: :destroy
  acts_as_readable :on => :updated_at

  validates_presence_of :video, :school_id, :user_id
  validates_attachment :video, presence: true

  has_attached_file :video, 
                path: ":folder_name/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                storage: :s3, 
                s3_host_name: PAPERCLIP_S3[:host_name], 
                bucket: PAPERCLIP_S3[:bucket], 
                s3_credentials: PAPERCLIP_S3[:credentials],                    
                :s3_permissions => :private,
                :styles => {
                  :flv => { :geometry => "1024x576", :format => 'flv', :convert_options => {:output => {:ar => 44100}} },
                  :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 3 }
                }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]


  validates_attachment :video, content_type: {content_type: ['application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/flv', 'video/x-flv', 'video/mp4', 'application/x-mp4', 'application/mp4', 'video/x-mp4','video/quicktime']}

  def video_url(style = 'original')
    begin
      video.expiring_url(108000, style)
    rescue Exception => e
      ""
    end  
  end   
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research on sidekiq so far and could you be more specific as to where you are struggling?

Comment: Yes... Just started with sidekiq..did not come across similar example to easily understand..

Comment: Start with a simple hello world type example for a queued task and replace that code then with your video processing code.

Comment: now i have used delayed paperclip gem with sidekiq.. https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/ .The video gets processed in background,, but this takes the same time as without using background processing. can't i show local video file with thumb to the user until background processing is done

Comment: I reckon there is no way around that (waiting the processing to finish) and background processing doesn't reduce processing time but frees the main (web-)server from heavy load by relegating the processing to a external server farm. My suggestion would be to tackle the processing in a 2 step routine: First generate the thumbnail and show a loading animation while in step 2 you process the video to the desired format.